# Opposite of fill-paragraph

Tags: text-editing

Emacs has the function `fill-paragraph`. Is there any function which will do the opposite of that?

I have a paragraph which is already filled and instead I want it in a plain single line?

Comment: `fill-paragraph` does *not* justify the paragraph, unless you use a prefix argument or pass it a non-`nil` first argument. See [(emacs) `Fill Commands`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quoting from [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillParagraph), by Stefan Monnier:

> Unfilling a paragraph joins all the lines in a paragraph into a single
>   line. It is the contrary of [FillParagraph](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillParagraph).
>
> It works where a line ends with a newline character (”\n”) and
>   paragraphs are separated by blank lines. To make a paragraph end in a
>   single newline then use the function below:
>
> ```
> ;;; It is the opposite of fill-paragraph    
> (defun unfill-paragraph ()
>   "Takes a multi-line paragraph and makes it into a single line of text."
>   (interactive)
>   (let ((fill-column (point-max)))
>     (fill-paragraph nil)))
> ```
>
> And to bind it to a key:
>
> ```
>  ;; Handy key definition
>  (define-key global-map "\M-Q" 'unfill-paragraph)
> ```
>
> See also [UnfillRegion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillRegion), and [UnwrapLine](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnwrapLine).

Comment: This is a straight copy from [Emacs Wiki page UnfillParagraph](http://www.emacswiki.org/UnfillParagraph), with the author (Stefan Monnier) attribution removed. It is helpful to post the info here, but at least make clear who wrote the code and link to that wiki page.

Comment: @Drew, yep. Is that a problem? If you want I will delete my answer.

Comment: It is simply polite to add attribution when you use someone's else information.

Comment: Thank you @nicael, I will be sure to do that in the future.

Comment: Thanks to Malabarba for making the changes.  @KingShimkus: nicael explained why this is better.

Comment: If you [post content written by someone else](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), you must acknowledge your sources.

Comment: Note the [link to the source](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillParagraph) changed. I edited it in the answer.

Comment: I've used this command happily for many years, but just now noticed a problem with it: if the first line in the region to be converted to a single line starts with a hyphen, then, if the first non-whitespace character of any of the following lines is a hyphen, then the latter hyphens disappear.

Answer (score 9):

My method would be placing the cursor in the last line of the paragraph and hitting <kbd>M-^</kbd> several times.

The beauty of this shortcut is that beside joining lines it reduces any amount of indentation spaces into single one.

Comment: AFAIK, you can do `M-^` and you need only hold the key down.  The function is named `delete-indentation`.

Comment: What is the function name for `M-S-^`, it doesn't seem to work for me ?

Comment: Yes the function is `delete-indentation` and the shortcut is described in Emacs as `M-^` - the shift (`S`) was added by me, because you have to hold it anyway. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 7):

There is the [`unfill` package](https://melpa.org/#/unfill) for this now.

> Provides commands for explicitly unfilling (ie. unwrapping)
> paragraphs and regions, and also a command that will toggle between
> filling and unfilling the current paragraph or region.

It is *based initially on [Xah Lee's](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_unfill-paragraph.html) [examples](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/modernization_fill-paragraph.html) and later rewritten based on [an article by Artur Malabarba](https://endlessparentheses.com/fill-and-unfill-paragraphs-with-a-single-key.html)*

It provide the following:

```
M-x unfill-region
M-x unfill-paragraph
M-x unfill-toggle
```

It's convenient to add an handy keybinging of your choice like:

```
;; Allow to fill or unfill with a single keybinding 
;; depending of the content status
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'unfill-toggle)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about this @easyE ?

Comment: My mistake:  the code based on Xah Lee's examples has *not* been incorporated as part of Emacs, but [*is* included as a MELPA package]( https://melpa.org/#/unfill).

Comment: @easyE I don't get the difference between your comment and the content of my answer, sorry.

Comment: I haven't argued that this is a difference.  I was mistaken in thinking the unfill pacakge had been included in Emacs 25, and then I corrected myself.

Comment: I found binding `unfill-paragraph` to be the exact antonym to `fill-paragraph`.

Comment: Nice one. This package really should be built-in in Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

A poor man's unfill can also be done by first setting the `fill-column` to some ridiculously high value (I use 9999) and then filling.  For instance, `C-u 9999 C-x f M-q C-u 70 C-x f`.  (Also, you might prefer `C-9 C-9 C-9 C-9` to `C-u 9999`.)

Comment: Actually a very good solution without needing a package as it retains some wanted paragraph filling logic Emacs provides.

Answer (score 1):

As always, there are several ways to do this, so I'll throw another answer in the ring:

1. Mark paragraph: <kbd>M-h</kbd>
2. Query replace newline with space in region:

   <kbd>M-%</kbd> <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In Evil mode there is the `J` key binding in `normal mode` from VIM. It joins the line below and the current line into one line. So by pressing it multiple times, you can undo fill-paragraph.

Comment: After the initial `J` press, you can also press `.` to repeat the previous command instead of having to hold down that pesky Shift.  ;)