# Key mapping: Push `M-q` once for fill-paragraph and twice for unfill-paragraph

Tags: key-bindings

There is an `unfill-paragraph` mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/opposite-of-fill-paragraph) that does the opposite of `fill-paragraph`. I would like to bind the key like the follows. `M-q` once to `fill-paragraph`. If the cursor does not move, push `M-q` again to `unfill-paragraph`. What is an elegant way to implement this in Emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer provided by @icarus does not let you keep toggling back and forth.  If you want that then you also need to set `this-command`, so that it alternates.

```el
(defun my-fill-paragraph (&optional arg)
  "Fill or unfill paragraph.  If repeated, alternate.
A prefix arg for filling means justify (as for `fill-paragraph')."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((fillp  (not (eq last-command 'fill-paragraph))))
    (apply (setq this-command  (if fillp 'fill-paragraph 'unfill-paragraph))
           (and fillp  arg  '(full t)))))
```

Comment: Using "icarus's answer" rather than "the answer of @icarus" stops stack exchange from notifying me.  In general I dislike updating `this-command`, although it works in this case. It stops you being able to use my-fill-paragraph as a function to call from some other toggle.  You should refactor the body to be `(interactive)(funcall (setq this-command (if (eq last-command #'fill-paragraph) #'unfill-paragraph #'fill-paragraph)))`. I look forward to you adding the support for prefix arg to be passed on to fill-paragraph.

Comment: @icarus: (I didn't know about "@icarus's".) Edited as suggested (except using a symbol, not a function object, for `this-command` value). HTH.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
(defun xuhdev/fill-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command this-command)
      (unfill-paragraph)
    (fill-paragraph)))
```

and then binding xuhdev/fill-paragraph to M-q perhaps? I can't say I am  a great fan of the idea, and I am leaving off support for arguments to fill-paragraph...